# Need help solving a pde with finite elements in matlab

Tags: matlab, numeric, finite-element-analysis

I have an initial value problem   u''''=f

with                 u(0)=u'(0)=u(1)=u'(1)=0

It comes then by multiplying with test function v and integrating to following formulation:

integral( 0 to 1) u''v'' dx= integral (o to 1) fv

So the basis function are polynomials of degree 3
And those polynomials can be solved exact with the simpson rule.

So I want to write some code to get the stiffness matrix for this..

I find it very hard to start with ..I don't have much experience in Matlab and would kindly ask you to help getting me started.

looking forward for any help!